# php construct vs php function

Tags: php

Trying to display multidimentional array using php construct does not work at all:

```
<?php
$_arr=array("Names"=>array("mola","dola","kola","hola"));

echo $_arr;
?>
```

but if ,we use **print_r()** function than it displays the whole array in a specific format why?

Comment: What are you looking to achieve exactly? `print_r()` is meant primarily for debugging and `echo` is not meant to output arrays directly.

Comment: Because it is written in the documentation

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis at the end: `$_arr=array("Names"=>array("mola","dola","kola","hola"));`

Comment: @Boaz than which method is meant  to output array?

Comment: Again, it depends on what you are looking to do with the array. You're most likely looking to output the array *elements* in some way, for which you should use some sort of iteration. ganeshrj's answer is an example of that.

Comment: @Boaz in javascript outputting rray was possible why not in php

Comment: @Maizere - because PHP !== javascript

Answer (score 2):

Try the `foreach` Statement

```
foreach($_arr as $key => $value)
{
   foreach($value as $v)   
      echo "$key  => $v<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: u missed "as" at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a parenthesis missmatch, the closing parenthesis is missing at the end of the array.

`echo $_arr;` should just return "array". `print_r($_arr)` "Prints human-readable information about a variable " see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

You Asked why..because this is the behaviour of this function? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `print_r` or `var_dump` to print your array. Otherwise, use `echo` in a `foreach` loop to iterate over the array. Another `foreach` inside the first one if you are iterating over a 2D array. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
function print_array($array){
 if(!is_array($array)){
  return false;
 }
 foreach($array as $v){
    if(is_array($v)){
      print_array($v);
    }
    else{
      echo "$v <br>\n";
    }
 }
}

print_array(array("one", array("a", "b", "c")));
```

Output:

```
one
a
b
c
```